# Get the same iv when using crypto to generate an iv

Tags: javascript, cryptography

I was using crypto to encrypt my data before store it in a json file. The problem is I only know how to generate a random iv.

I tried looking around the web but I didn't find anything about it. I also tried storing the iv in a json file but it becomes unusable.

I commented out the html stuff so i could use it from the cmd prompt.

```
//const submit = document.getElementById('submit')
//const username = document.getElementById('username')
//const password = document.getElementById('password')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const fs = require('fs')
const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)
let key = '3956349e7a64b865ddcb5bac3af67490'

function load(){
  const raw_data = fs.readFileSync('LJib.json')
  const data = JSON.parse(raw_data)
  let decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
  let decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf-8')
  decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8')
  return JSON.parse(decrypted)
}

function save(data){
  data = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data))
  let cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv)
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf-8', 'hex')
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex')
  encrypted = JSON.stringify(encrypted)
  fs.writeFileSync('LJib.json', encrypted)
}

function main(){
  submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var data = load()
    save(data)
  })
}

save({'user' : 'password'})
console.log(load())
```

Really I just need a way to get the same iv constantly rather than getting a random one with `crypto.randomBytes(16)`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually IVs should be random and not constant. IVs are public, so you can and you should store it plain with the encrypted text.  The best solution is to use a standard format for encryption, like PKCS#7's enveloped data, but you'd need a different library for that, like Forge.

As IVs usually have a fixed length, you could simply pre-append the IV with the encrypted data before storing it in the file, or maybe put it in a json structure, like the example bellow, and save the structure in the file. Just remember you can't put raw binary data in json structures, before you have to convert it to a "printable" string (e.g.: hex string, base 64, etc.).

```
{ 
   "iv" : "...iv data...",
   "encrypted" : "...encrypted_data_.."
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I just had to do

```
const iv = Buffer.alloc(16, 2)
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: [Predictable IVs are a terrible idea](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3883/why-is-cbc-with-predictable-iv-considered-insecure-against-chosen-plaintext-atta). IVs exist for a reason. Don't invent your own crypto.